# Global keyboard shortcut for adding an event/reminder to iCal

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, osx-lion, calendar.app

What is the best way in OS X Lion to have a global keyboard shortcut for adding an event/reminder to iCal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Fantastical](http://flexibits.com/)

   [image]
2. [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) or [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) plus:

   ```
   activate application "iCal"
   tell application "System Events" to keystroke "n" using command down
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If all you're looking for is a quick way to add a reminder straight into iCal, use [Remind Me Later](http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/remind-me-later/id408236729?mt=12)

Answer (score 0):

There is a good [Alfred extension](http://www.dirtdon.com/?p=1261) extension which does this neatly:

[image: Alfred extension]

Comment: Link no longer valid (404)